# Расширение файла через with ... as

Tags: python

Возможно ли заранее указать в программе расширение в котором необходимо сохранять файл пользователя?

```
name = input('Введите название файла: ')
func = input('Что записать?: ')
with open(name, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as x:
    x.write(func)
    print('Ваша информация записана в ' + name)

print(x)
```

Comment: А в чем проблема пишите полное название файла, все будет работать.

Comment: Это понятно! Хотелось бы это сделать за пользователя!

Comment: ну так сделайте. Это просто как сложить две строки.

Comment: `name + '.txt'`, например...

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!